# loading Spine.Tabs in rails

Tags: spine.js

I'm working on a rails app and using spine, I want to use the Spine.Tabs feature, inside the IDE (rubymine) I can go to the Tabs class but it's not loaded when I run the site, what to add and where for tabs to load? I'm using the gem spine rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tabs logic is not loaded by default in a Spine app. You need to require it before you start loading your app classes.

You need to require it in your assets/javascripts/app/index.js.coffee (or whichever file loads up your rails app) after you required spine.

So for me I would end up with this:

```
#= require json2
#= require jquery
#= require spine/spine
#= require spine/manager
#= require spine/ajax
#= require spine/route
#= require spine/relation
#= require spine/tabs # added this.

#= require_tree ./lib
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./stacks
#= require_tree ./views
```